# How to store cumulated data after Scrapy has finished working with every URL?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to store some data after Scrapy has finished working (i.e after it did every URL I asked him). 
Everytime Scrapy parse some result (through the parse function in the spider class), I append some information to an existing global object in the class itself. I would like to access that object at the end, and if possible to do everything from a Python script. Here's my spider code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


from newsScrapy.items import NewsscrapyItem

class newsScrapySpider(Spider):
    name = "newsScrapy"
    start_urls = []

    global wordMatrix
    wordMatrix = {}

    global prefix
    prefix = "http://www.nytimes.com/indexes/"
    sufix = "/todayspaper/index.html"
    for year in range (2000,2015):
        for month in range (1,13):
            for day in range (1,32):
                if(month<10 and day<10):
                    start_urls.append (prefix+str(year)+"/"+"0"+str(month)+"/"+"0"+str(day))
                elif (month<10 and day>9):
                    start_urls.append (prefix+str(year)+"/"+"0"+str(month)+"/"+str(day))
                elif (month>9 and day<10):
                    start_urls.append (prefix+str(year)+"/"+str(month)+"/"+"0"+str(day))
                else:
                    start_urls.append (prefix+str(year)+"/"+str(month)+"/"+str(day))

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        items = []
        text = sel.xpath('//body//text()').re('(\w+)')

        item = NewsscrapyItem()

        item['body'] = text
        item['date'] = response.url.strip(prefix)

        items.append(item)

        for word in item['body']:
            word = word.strip(' ').strip(',').strip('\n')
            word = word.lower()
            if (not word in stopwords.words('english')):
                if(wordMatrix.__contains__((word, item['date']))):
                    wordMatrix[word,item['date']]+=1
                else:
                    wordMatrix[word, item['date']]=1


        # print wordMatrix
        return items
```

The idea would be to access the wordMatrix variable after the end of the scraping (once every data was collected) and to do it from another Python script (for ploting per example). 
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Together with your existing imports:

```
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle
```

And then just before `return items`:

```
pickle.dump(wordMatrix, '/path/to/file/wordMatrix.data');
```

In another script you can load this data with:

```
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle

wordMatrix = pickle.load('/path/to/file/wordMatrix.data')
```

`Pickling` is a process of serializing and deserializing any Python object. There are two implementations in Python standard library - `pickle` is pure Python and `cPickle` is written in C thus much faster. The unusual import code tries to import faster one but for instance IronPython lacks cPickle and in this case the latter is imported. Both modules do exactly the same and share the same interface.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't do what I'm looking for. With that method, the data is dumped at every call (and not only the last one). Besides, I need it to be the cumulated data, not only for the last request.

Comment: You haven't provided the code which calls `parse(self, response)` but since my solution actually stores the data, you should just move it to the place where you have all data collected.